# visual studio- test cases as workitems under work tab and test cases under test tab

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

What is the difference between creating test cases as workitems under work tab and creating test cases after creating a test plan under test tab in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Test tab, the records will be automatically linked, so that Test Cases are part of a Suite and so on.

The link to the requirements happens also, if you use the *Add Test* contextual menu in a Board.

[image: Add Test Case from Board]

You can create a Test Case from the *New Work Item* menu, but then you have to add all the Links yourself.

[image: Use New Work Item menu]